# Wordpress - HTML link in website only works after refresh

Tags: html, wordpress

I put a simple link (popup) in my Wordpress site (the code is just in the content editor), and this link only works after I refresh my website once…

```
<a class="widget qode-popup-opener">
<span class="qode-popup-opener-text">I have a question about this product</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I am asking myself now: Why shouldn't it? Of course you have to refresh the site to load the new code.

Comment: I have to refresh the page EVERY time, so the first time u enter the page, the link doesn't work. After the refresh it does... Here is the link:
https://deviant-design.be/gallery/vintage-chair-2/

Comment: The popup logic is in some javascript-library, with this minimal information, we have no way of knowing why that library might fail. Are there errors in console?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference ||| ajax.min.js (1,15368)

Comment: @C4mps So you have javascript-errors, get at the bottom of them and you might find what you need.

Comment: I am an amateur in HTML/CSS (Web development in general) I didn't think about using the Console... Thank you very much.